Analytic form for the cummulative propability of a brownian bridge?
The probability density of a brownian bridge, starting at $t=0,x=x_0$ and ending at $t=T,x=0$ is given by
$$p(x,t;x_0,T)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-t/T)t}}\exp(\frac{-(x-x_0(1-t/T))^2}{2(1-t/T)t})$$
or for more dimensions, we just multiply this by itself with possibly different $x_0$.
Is there an analytic expression known in the literature about the cumulative probability, i.e.
$$\int_0^T p(x,t;x_0,T) dt$$
in particular for three dimensions?
Would appreciate any help or pointers!
